# TypeError: 'x' is not a function even when the method is defined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typeerror

I am running some tests on to a file for which I am getting this weird error as TypeError: this.activatedService.isVariableActivated is not a function even when the function is defined.

This is my code snippet in a typescript file activation.ts -

```
import { ActivationService } from 'activationService'
constructor(
   private activatedService: ActivationService)
onActivationVariable(testvar: string) {
{
  this.activatedService.isVariableActivated('ACTIVATION').then(
    isActivated => {
      console.log('value of isActivated:', isActivated);
      if (isActivated) {
           /*some functionality*/
      });
```

This is my function definition in a class in another service typescript file activationService.ts

```
export declare class ActivationService {
isVariableActivated(variableName: string, customTarget?: string): Promise<Boolean>;
}
```

When I am calling the isVariableActivated function from the onActivationVariable function, I am getting this error -

```
TypeError: this.activatedService.isVariableActivated is not a function
```

I am new to angular/javascript. Can anyone help me regarding this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: use the `static` before `isVariableActivated` method in `ActivationService` class

Comment: the instance of ActivationService has no such function can we see its code?

Answer (score 0):

If your activedService in the constructor is supposed to be the **ActivationService class itself**, you have to define it with keyword static, so it becomes the class's method.

```
       export declare class ActivationService {
       static isVariableActivated(variableName: string, customTarget?: 
       string): 
       Promise<Boolean>;
       }
```

If activedService is meant to be **an instance of ActivationService**, you need to use the new keyword:

```
constructor(
private activatedService: new ActivationService())
onActivationVariable(testvar: string) {
{ ....
```

Comment: I tried to include static but it is not working it seems.. :(